# Get the sum of a column along with the records

Tags: mysql

I have a table of the type:

```
id | amount
-----------
1  |  10
2  |  5
3  |  7
```

I would like to get the rows records plus the sum of 'amount' column all in 1 query, something like this:

```
1  10 22
2  5  22
3  7  22
```

I am trying:

```
SELECT *, sum(amount)
FROM table GROUP BY id
```

But it is not working. Any ideas how could I solve this? Is it possible? Is it efficient for a very large database? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried this same exact syntax and it worked for me.

Comment: My original syntax returns only one record. I needed all records plus a column with the sum of the cells of that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT t.*, (select sum(amount) from tbl t) as total_amount
FROM table t1 GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: great!!! thank you very much!!!! it does not need the `GROUP BY id` anymore either